# Check existence of value from database table

Tags: ado.net

I have an UI having multiple controls one of control is for enter id, when user enter a particular ID and press enter then I want to check that ID against a specific column of a table from the database.

How can I do this using ADO.NET ? Please put code reference for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a method that would take the `id` and use a `SqlCommand` to execute the query:

```
public bool ItemExists(int id)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM some_table WHERE id = @id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar;
        return count > 0;
    }
}
```